# How to take off WordPress twenty seventeen theme home page header image scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

By default my WordPress twenty seventeen theme, **home page header** image is having scrolling effect, it's scrolling over until just main menu is on top. I want to make a header image fixed at one moment. The height of image when it's fixed should be like in other pages when they open up. Also I want to fix the height of header images that is on all other pages.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following code will help

```
.has-header-image .custom-header-media img
{
   position:inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: This makes image from: position: fixed to position: inherit, but this is not what i am looking for. I want to make header image like a menu, which is fixed when scroll up till top.

Comment: Then make the position fixed instead of inherit. Hope that will do